# How to find a basis for this set of polynomials with matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, matlab

I'm new on Matlab tools. Teacher told me to find the basis for this polynomials using matlab:

$$ -15 -x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5 $$
$$ -35+x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5 $$
$$ -70+x+3x^2+6x^3+10x^4+15x^5 $$
$$ -126+x+4x^2+10x^3+20x^4+35x^5 $$
$$ -210+x+5x^2+15x^3+35x^4+70x^5 $$

So, all I know is define the matrix relative to this system. How to proceed? 
Please help me step by step. I don't know how to to solve the problem in matlab, but I know how to do it with paper.

Comment: what tag must I add?

Comment: What do you mean by "find the basis"? What you've written is probably already a basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most $5$.

Comment: could you then please add what you would do on paper?